# Spring Boot TLS v1.2 enabled but package exchange not deteced with Wireshark

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ssl, tls1.2

I have enabled Spring Boot SSL/TLS with the following properties in the **application.properies** file:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:security/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=springboot
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
server.ssl.enabled=true
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,TLS_ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,TLS_ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,TLS_ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384TLS_ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384,TLS_ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256,TLS_ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

and I have also configured the HTTP connector to redirect traffic request on port 8080 to port 8443 with this lines in a configuration class

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletFactory(){
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context){

                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };

        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {

        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
```

Everything works fine but if I scan my traffic using **Wireshark** I can't find TLSv1.2 protocol packages but only TCP packages. 
Is this the correct behavior or is there anything wrong?

Thanks to all.

**UPDATE**
These are the screenshots from Wireshark:
[myApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9KKM.png), [captured searching Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNF2o.png)

Comment: TLS runs on top of TCP, so ...

Comment: Yes I know, but if I go on facebook.com for example I can see the TLS handshake and all the transmition with the packages marked as TLSv1.2. With my application I see only TCP without details of TLS.

Comment: What is in the payload if you right-click and "Follow TCP session... " for your packets on port 8443?

Comment: The payload contains the information about my self signed certificate and other sequence of characters (setting result view as ASCII)

Comment: Then it seems like the data is TLS. You just need to persuade Wireshark to show it as such. It's probably configured to decode TLS packets based on port number.

Comment: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/12360/mapping-a-well-known-protocol-to-a-custom-port

Comment: It works! if you answer my question i mark it as correct, thanks a lot!